# What is the best way to connect different LEDs?

Tags: led, parallel, led-strip, series

I'm working on my first PCB for horticulture lighting and wondering what is the best way to connect all LEDs. The idea is to use both white LEDs (using Samsung's LM301H LEDs that require 2.75V@65mA [datasheet](https://cdn.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2020/03/Data_Sheet_LM301H_CRI70_Rev.2.1.pdf)) and red LEDs (using Samsung LH351H LEDs that require 2.2V@350mA [datasheet](https://cdn.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2021/01/Data_Sheet_LH351H_660nm_Red_Rev.2.3.pdf)) but since those require different currents I'm not completely sure if I'm connecting them appropriately, and I've been struggling to find any tips on the subject. The current wiring is as follows, in total there are 72 white LEDs and 4 red LEDs. The white LEDs are connected in series of 12 times 6 in parallel, thus this block should require 33V@390mA. Then the red LEDs are connected in series after this block, hence the entire PCB should require 41.8V (33+2.2*4) @ between 350 and 390mA. I'm not using any resistors since the PCB will be connected to a constant current driver. My questions are:

- Are there any problems in having the first block draw a slightly different current than the following red LEDs, if so what do you suggest me to change?
- Are there any samples of resources that explain/simplify the process of connecting different types of LEDs without using resistors?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Please draw a schematic, I can't tell what you mean from words alone.

Comment: A link to the LED datasheets would be useful

Comment: I've added the datasheets and schematics

Comment: To wire LEDs in parallel they should have the same Vf (forward voltage). In the datasheet I see they are binned by Vf with a tolerance of 0.1V which is what you need, so please confirm all your LEDs are in the same Vf bin (labeled AY or AZ or A1 in datasheet)

Comment: How will you dissipate the heat?

Comment: What is a Vf bin? I'm planning on printing it on an aluminum PCB which I will glue with termal tape to an aluminum extrusion.

Comment: OK! If you do an aluminium pcb then no problem. As for "Vf binning" search for "A1" in datasheet, these LEDs are sorted (binned) by forward voltage so when you wire them in parallel they share current well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you must not connect *different* LEDs in parallel and I wouldn't even connect different color temperatures in parallel even though they share the same datasheet (in case of LM301). The different phosphorus coatings might introduce different power dissipation, which can lead to thermal runaway (a pretty important effect you should look up).

For high power applications, a pure series connection is not practical, though, as you would either require many separate drivers or a high voltage. So a parallel connection is quite common, but you should make sure to only assemble binned chips and leave some current margin (so you stay in specs in case of thermal runaway).

"Are there any problems in having the first block draw a slightly different current than the following red LEDs" - thats not a problem as long as you don't exceed any of the leds' current ratings.

"Are there any samples of resources that explain/simplify the process of connecting different types of LEDs without using resistors?" - you should learn about the mentioned thermal runaway (TR). This effect makes parallel connections of semiconductors generally unstable in theory. In practice, you will have Ohmic losses to some extend (pcb traces, bonding wires in the led) which can compensate the effect of TR if you have sufficiently well-binned LEDs. Also make sure to have good thermal connection between the LEDs. A special case is when the entire parallel current is below the current the single LEDs are rated for. In this case, thermal runaway may still occur, but it is not fatal.

Comment: I apologize I did a mistake and wrote LM301B when I meant LH351H. Other than that thanks for the answer! If I understood correctly then wiring I've done is fine as long as I limit the current to 390mA (since the maximum current for red LEDs is 1A).

Comment: @FlavioSchneider Ah, I see! Your schematic is absolutely fine, but make sure to only use binned LM301s.